# SQL error on iOS5 but not iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I am using `sqlite` in an app for iOS, and it was working perfectly fine to retrieve objects from the data base on iOS4. But on iOS5, when I execute a statement (using the function `sqlite3_step`), it sometimes returns a `SQLITE_CORRUPT` error (meaning that "The database disk image is malformed").

The request fails upon this error. When using a third party app to inspect this database I also stumble on this error.

My question is: why has changed between iOS4 and 5 to stop the request to work just fine? Is there a way to configure `sqlite` on iOS to ignore this kind of error?

I precise that I'm using the very same code and database on the 2 version of the OS....